# Help me understand this Haskell (GHCI) type error: (Num [Char]) when appending number to string

Tags: haskell, types, ghci

I've been doing my annual attempt to learn Haskell this weekend, and as ever when I actually try to write a recursive function (rather than just type one in from a tutorial), I get a type error.

I'd very much appreciate any help understanding (1) what the error means (I don't understand the "fix"); and (2) why an error is being thrown at all - I'm fairly certain I'm not making any mistakes regarding the types being passed.

My code:

```
tell :: (Show a) => [a] -> String  
tell'in :: (Show a, Num n) => [a] -> n -> String -> (n, String)
tell [] = "The list is empty"  
tell (x:[]) = "The list has one element: " ++ show x  
tell (x:xs) = "The list has " ++ n ++ " elements: " ++ s where (n, s) = (tell'in (xs) (1) (show x))  


tell'in (x:[]) n s = ((n + 1), (s ++ " and " ++ (show x)))
tell'in (x:xs) n s = tell'in xs (n+1)  (s ++ " and " ++ show x)
```

And the error I get when I try to load this into GHCI:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( example.hs, interpreted )

example.hs:13:88:
    Could not deduce (Num [Char]) arising from the literal `1'
    from the context (Show a)
      bound by the type signature for tell :: Show a => [a] -> String
      at example.hs:(11,1)-(13,99)
    Possible fix:
      add (Num [Char]) to the context of
        the type signature for tell :: Show a => [a] -> String
      or add an instance declaration for (Num [Char])
    In the second argument of `tell'in', namely `(1)'
    In the expression: (tell'in (xs) (1) (show x))
    In a pattern binding: (n, s) = (tell'in (xs) (1) (show x))
Failed, modules loaded: none.
Prelude>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tell'in` is returning a `Num n => n`, which you are then `(++)`ing with a `String` (aka `[Char]`) in the last equation for `tell`.  You probably want to use `show n` instead of `n` there.

Answer (score 2):

The type of `tell'in` says that the first coordinate of its return value will be the same type as its second argument.  In `tell`, you are calling `tell'in` with a number as its second argument (`1`), and then using the first coordinate of its return value (`n`) as a string by appending it to other strings.  So whatever this type is, it must simultaneously be a string and a number.  The error is telling you that there is no way for a string (`[Char]`) to be considered a kind of number, which arises when it tries to interpret the meaning of the numeric literal `1`. You probably meant

```
"The list has " ++ show n ++ " elements: " ++ ...
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a general scheme to understand the compile error, iff it is some type mismatch:
You need to supply more specific type annotations to narrow the error down!

`tell'in` and `tell` already have types:

```
tell :: (Show a) => [a] -> String  
tell'in :: (Show a, Num n) => [a] -> n -> String -> (n, String)
```

So, you change this:

```
tell (x:xs) = "The list has " ++ n ++ " elements: " ++ s
    where (n, s) = tell'in (xs) (1) (show x))
```

To this:

```
--   vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv                      vvvvvvvv
tell ((x:xs)::(Show a=>[a])) = "The list has " ++ (n::Int) ++ " elements: " ++ s
    where (n::Int, s::String) = tell'in (xs) (1::Int) (show x)) 
--        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^               ^^^^^^^^
```

Now, either you already see the error, or you try to compile again and have a more specific error message.

---

Anyway, it is a good idea to use `::Int` instead of `::Num n=>n`, because the latter will generalize to `::Integer`, whenever the exact type is not specified. The `Int` is not larger than one machine word (32/64bit) and therefore it is faster than the arbitrary-sized `Integer`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that in future.